# Validation (CSS 3.0): 'text-overflow' is not a known CSS property name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css

I have a column in asp.net gridview. The string in the column is very long and no white space. So I want to wrap it with ellipsis.
But I can't use text-overflow since it is not recongnized by CSS.
My code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MD9" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 200px;  overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                            <%# Eval("MD9")%>
                            ></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

How to change it?

Comment: You mean it's not recognized by the Visual Studio CSS validator? Well, who cares... (it will work in the browsers)

Comment: Well, I want to click the ellipsis then expand the rest text but failed.

Comment: The `text-overflow` property (like CSS in general) defines presentation, not behavior. You probably want a JavaScript click-handler. With CSS, you can only achieve a "hover" handler - http://jsfiddle.net/sW4G5/

Comment: Oop, it is hard to fire an event against ellipsis. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think the ellipsis from `text-overflow:ellipsis` are reachable with JavaScript. You could bind the click handler on the DIV...

Comment: Reslove it by myself: using

`word-wrap: break-word;
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your CSS3 Intellisense Schema with the [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83).